# Magento 1.9 Persisitent Cache Categorie until reboot

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

I setup a magento store that is in production since a year and half with no issue except this one :
For performance reason i put `/var/www/html/var/cache` and `/var/www/html/var/session` in a ramdisk using the following code

```
tmpfs -o size=128m /var/www/html/var/cache tmpfs defaults,uid=apache,gid=apache,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs -o size=128m /var/www/html/var/session tmpfs defaults,uid=apache,gid=apache,mode=755 0 0
```

With apc and this setup the store is fast enough for us small target.

The problem i have with this setup is following : when i create a new categorie (menu or not), they appear frontend only if cache is dissable in Magento.
If i enable again the cache the new categorie dissapear again.

This happen even if i flush the cache before from admin, (the both folder i could watch from fizella become empty) or using `*rm -rdf /var/www/html/var/cache/*` in command line

If i reboot the server, everything will work fine i could enable the cache in the admin and the the new categorie create front end.
I have a similar issue with the home slider.
Except that the store works as normal, new product appear normally frontend with this setup.

If i dissable the ramdisk everything work totally normal, i could create new categorie and they appear immediatly frontend

Seems there is some persistent file in ramdisk even if i flush the cache from admin or using `*rm -rdf /var/www/html/var/cache/*`

Any idea how totally flush the cache of tmpfs ramdisk partition ? seems there is some persitent cache file in it, until reboot
Ramdisk really boost the store on a small server without ssd, so i will be happy to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found how to solve the issue :

```
tmpfs -o size=128m /var/www/html/var/cache tmpfs defaults,uid=apache,gid=apache,mode=755 0 0
```

The defaults options = rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async
I just removed it, no sure wich option removed make the trick but now its works (i was thinking async / sync, thats its not ideal but the server perform as before)
I could now create new menu,slider and i just have to clear cache from admin.
No more reboot and happy
Thanks